# SpriteKit Music & Sound FX Management

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

In SpriteKit, texture atlases are a great tool when it comes to managing art assets. Is there an equivalent for managing sound files? In my game I will have a lot of short sound FX and some music files that are longer and will be looped.

I've decided on creating a class just for this purpose called `AudioEngine`, but what I can't decide upon is how to store the sounds in the project. Should I keep track of them in a plist of some sort or just scan for all .caf, .wav, etc files? I'm sorry if this sounds like an opinion based question, but I'd like to know what the best practices are for this.

Comment: Main purpose of atlases is to improve memory and rendering performance (by enabling batch rendering feature), not organizing files inside project. About how you can store sound files inside your project, that is pretty much opinion based...But my answer would be - store it as you find most suitable. Because how you store sound files on disc, probably can't affect on performance. Important thing is, how you preload, play and manipulate with those sounds etc.